# How do I find what other pages users who have liked my page have liked? [facebook]

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am using restfb version 2.0.0-rc.1 as the java library and eclipse for this.

I have as of now just managed to get the number of likes on my page using the following code

```
    FacebookClient fbClient2 = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);

    Page page = fbClient2.fetchObject("me", Page.class);

    System.out.println("page name is: "+page.getLikesCount());
```

How do i go ahead? 
Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: You ask your users to login to your Facebook app and grant you user_likes permission

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the users who liked your Page with the API, and there is no way to get the information about other Pages your fans have liked. You can only get the number of likes, or you can authorize users with the `user_likes` permission to get their Page likes.